# jQuery in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, slider

I've written a little slider script in jQuery which I want to run in my Magento store. I have included this script in my view.phtml but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to Magento and have no idea on how to add custom scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// < ![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var active = 0; // starts at zero
        var list = jQuery('ul');

        list.children('li').eq('0').siblings().hide(); // Hide all except first list element

       jQuery('.next').bind('click', function() {
            active = active == list.children('li').length-1 ? 0 : active + 1;
        });

        jQuery('.prev').bind('click', function() {
            active = active == 0 ? list.children('li').length-1 : active - 1;
        });

        var getActive = function() {
            return list.children('li').eq(active);
        };

        jQuery('.prev,.next').bind('click', function() {
            getActive().fadeIn().siblings().hide();
        });

 });// ]]></script>
```

And here is my HTML in view.phtml:

```
<ul>
   <li>img1</li>
   <li>img1</li>
   <li>img1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first: **Magento does not use jQuery**.

**Magento uses [PrototypeJs](http://prototypejs.org/)**, and either convert your jQuery into PrototypeJs or you have to load jQuery, use the [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method so they both run seamlessly.

To load jQuery in your page, either you use the `.xml` template to load it into all your pages, or if it's only in this particular page, you could simply load it before your script, for example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
   // noConflict so we can use both libraries
   $.noConflict(); 

   // your current code here

//]]>
</script>
```

if you want to load in all pages through your design template, [here is a suggestion](http://css-tricks.com/using-jquery-in-magneto/).

Comment: Thanx! I added a jQuery Extension for Magento and that is why I used jQuery. I've never used prototype. Is there some simple way to convert this code to prototype.js?

Comment: no, and I'm also not so much familiar with prototype, only for the basic stuff... use Magento Forums to ask about that extension or search for help on that extension, if you have installed and of course, refresh the cache, and still doesn't work, do that, or remove it completely and apply the example code I have provided / read the provided link to load jQuery for all pages manually.