# Jquery is undefined but function executes fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

On the checkout page in magento i am getting this error:

`VarienForm is not defined
[Break On This Error]`

var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);

But when I enter my username and password, it logs me in. Can I remove the error?

PS: I have moved varien js library to the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you script isn't working - that's it. The fact, that you are being logged in has nothing to do with the VarienForm object - this is a HTML form with submit button, so of course it submits and logs you in. VarienForm's main task is to validate form data before submit. So usually if you try to log in with empty password or login, VariendForm prevents form from being submitted. In your case, when script is broken, it just won't do anything before submit.

So, sorry, but the best advice would be - don't move this library. Yes, you can fix every single page, where you will meet this error, but it will take a lot of time. And if you will install 3rd party extensions, you will most likely have to modify them too. I don't think, that such optimization is worth it.

PS. And unless you are toying with Magento 2, VarienForm is based on Prototype, not jQuery, so your tags are incorrect and SnapGravy's code most likely won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to call a function that has not been defined yet, in JavaScript you need to declare variables, functions and objects before they are used.

If you move all the definitions to the footer and try to call them in the middle of the page you will get "not defined" errors.

```
// Example Success
var test = "OK!";
alert(test) // Alerts: OK!

// Example Fail
alert(test); // Alerts: undefined
var test = "OK!";
```

Simple example but it goes for everything as mentioned above, everything you use has to be defined before its used.

```
$(function() {

    // Define VarienForm here somewhere
    var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);

});
```

This code should run on your page without undefined errors and can be placed in footer or header.

Comment: Thanks @SnapGravy, But the problem is that the function gets executed. Is there any workaround that i dont get the error.

Comment: @shaktiman1234 Cant really say without seeing more code. It was more or less taking a shot in the dark based on the information provided as the error is based on undefined definitions. The error should dissapear if you make sure VarienForm is defined before it is used though.

Comment: I was trying to move all the js to the footer so that page load time decreases. If I define VarienForm before then whole purpose will be forefeited.

Comment: @shaktiman1234 You can use loaders such as head.js or require.js to optimize your JavaScript. But you can also make sure that VarienForm is defined before it is used even if its in the footer. But without knowing how you set up your code it just gets harder to give you a definite solution to your problem.

If provide a more in depth example of your setup you would probably get some better feedback. Your issues are definitely solvable though.

I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably a javascript framework conflict.

jQuery conflicts with Prototype which is what's used by preference in the cart functions, validations and window shade effect.

Load jQuery in the head before Prototype and then invoke the jQuery noconflict function.

Answered here [jQuery in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933199/jquery-in-magento)

Move the varien stuff back to where it belongs. Frameworks need to load before the page loads so they'll properly function.